# Help with identity functions in discrete mathematics

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have trouble with trying to solve the following problem:

For nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ and functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ suppose that $g\circ f=i_A$, the identity function on A.

a) Show that $f$ is not necessarily surjective.

b) Show that $g$ is not necessarily injective.

c) Prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if $g$ is injective.

I have trouble getting started, thus I don't have much work here so I apologize for that. I just started on this subject today and have trouble grasping everything right now and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Note first that $g\circ f:A\rightarrow A$.    $~~~g\circ f=i_A$ means that $g(f(a))=a, ~\forall a\in A$. So, since $g$ maps from $B$ to $A$, provided that $f(a)\in B$, $g(f(a))$ is well-defined.

Suppose that $f$ isn't surjective. We would still have that $g(f(a) = a, ~\forall a\in A$.

Comment: Sorry in my first comment I'm waffling a bit. I'm trying not to just write out a solution. Graphically, a) is picking at this: http://i.imgur.com/bYOPHCq.png. We see that f does not map to the whole of B, so it is not surjective. However, if you take any element in A, perform f then g onto it, by construction you have $i_A$. So it satisfies everything you want as set out in the question, but it is not necessarily surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

a) Set $f(x) = x$ and use sets such that $A \subsetneq B$, e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

b) See a).

c) Suppose that $g$ is not injective, then there exist $b_1 \neq b_2$ such that $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$. Suppose that $f$ is surjective, that is, there exist $a_1 \neq a_2$ such that $f(a_i) = b_i$. We obtain contradiction between $a_1 = (g \circ f)(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_2) = a_2$ and $a_1 \neq a_2$. Proceed with the other direction similarly.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Just discovered `\smile` here. I guess I shouldn't have been surprised.

Comment: Hi, thank you that makes everything more clear. However, I am unsure about the 2nd part of c).

Comment: @LaswjdfAsdfa I won't solve this question for you. It's in your reach, just try a bit harder $\ddot\smile$